# Fetch Duplicate records with where clause in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

```
Sno|PID |Tests|Result
1   1001 HB    10
2   1001 HB    12
3   1001 TEMP  98
4   1002 TEMP  98  
5   1002 HB    120
6   1003 TEMP   98
```

**Query 1** - I need only those records where Test - HB is done more than 1. In the above case, the output would be the first two rows. {I need duplicate rows}

I am trying it with below query but does not work

```
SELECT  PID,test_name, COUNT(MRN) AS dup
FROM `report` WHERE Tests = 'HB' GROUP BY Tests HAVING dup > 1
```

**Query 2** - I need only those records where Test - HB is not done at all. In the above case, the output would be the last row. PID - 1003

Thanks

Comment: There no MRN  is your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this:

```
SELECT r1.*
FROM report r1
WHERE
    Tests = 'HB' AND
    Sno IN (SELECT Sno FROM report r2
            WHERE Tests = 'HB' GROUP BY Sno HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

For the second requirement, you may try:

```
SELECT r1.*
FROM report r1
WHERE
    Tests <> 'HB' AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM report r2
                WHERE r2.PID = r1.PID AND r2.Tests = 'HB');
```

Comment: Thanks, first query works like charm but for the second query it is very slow. Hence I modified it little and it works for me. Select * from reports where PID not in (select PID from table where TESTS=HB)

Comment: @Lucifer I had a slight problem with the logic of my second query.  In fact, using exists should be the best option here.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider window functions.  The first query is:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*, sum(tests = 'HB') over (partition by pid) as num_hb
      from reports r
     ) r
where tests = 'HB' and num_hb >= 2;
```

The second is:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*, sum(tests = 'HB') over (partition by pid) as num_hb
      from reports r
     ) r
where num_hb = 0;
```